# Why does my database connection closed when attempting to execute SQL generated by JOOQ?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jooq

Database connection closing when I attempt to run some SQL using JOOQ's statically typed fields

I am using JOOQ https://www.jooq.org/ for type safe SQL but for some reason the connection closes and I have no clue to why. I have a psql 9.6 database which I have enabled all logging but the connection closes before running the JOOQ generated query, exception is shown lower down.

```
var blockRecord = db.execute(sql -> sql.select(ATTENDANCE.BLOCK_TIME.BLOCK_ID).from(ATTENDANCE.BLOCK_TIME)
                .where(ATTENDANCE.BLOCK_TIME.CLIENT_ID.eq(clientId))
                        .and(ATTENDANCE.BLOCK_TIME.START_TIME.eq(startTime)))
                        .and(ATTENDANCE.BLOCK_TIME.SCHEDULE_ID.eq(scheduleId)).fetchOne().value1();
```

However, the connection stays opens and presents no problems when I run sql this way:

```
     //Injection vulnerable
        String query = "SELECT block_id FROM attendance.block_time " +
                "WHERE start_time = cast ( '" + startTime + "' as timestamp) "  + " and client_id = '" + clientId + "' and schedule_id = '" + scheduleId + "'";

        var record = db.execute(sql -> sql.fetch(query));
```

Error thrown:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: jOOQ; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into "attendance"."attendance_override" ("client_id", "client_reference", "schedule_id", "block_id", "status") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Connection is closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
L state [null]; error code [0]; Connection is closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at org.jooq_3.11.9.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at id.acme.service.dbcommon.ExceptionTranslator.exception(ExceptionTranslator.java:32)
    at org.jooq.impl.ExecuteListeners.exception(ExecuteListeners.java:251)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:365)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:127)
    at id.acme.service.attendance.services.ImportService.submitMoodleRecords(ImportService.java:125)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at id.acme.service.common.api.ServiceRegistry.invokeRpc(ServiceRegistry.java:118)
    at id.acme.service.common.api.Dispatcher.processRequest(Dispatcher.java:167)
    at id.acme.service.common.api.Dispatcher.tryHandle(Dispatcher.java:86)
    at id.acme.service.common.api.TopLevelMessageHandler.handle(TopLevelMessageHandler.java:43)
    at id.acme.service.common.api.WebSocketDelegate.dispatchMessage(WebSocketDelegate.java:194)
    at id.acme.service.common.api.WebSocketDelegate.onTextMessage(WebSocketDelegate.java:137)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.annotated.CallableMethod.call(CallableMethod.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.annotated.OptionalSessionCallableMethod.call(OptionalSessionCallableMethod.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyAnnotatedEventDriver$2.run(JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:489)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:311)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcTemplate.java:1526)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.ProviderEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(ProviderEnabledConnection.java:109)
    at org.jooq.impl.SettingsEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(SettingsEnabledConnection.java:73)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.prepare(AbstractQuery.java:416)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.prepare(AbstractDMLQuery.java:512)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:322)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I expected the connection to close on both, however only closes when the query/statement is prepared by JOOQ....

Comment: @knutwannheden, Thank you, please make this an answer because this worked perfectly!!!

Comment: @TheMuscleCode Excellent. I will just delete my comment in favor of Lukas' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your `db.execute()` does, but there's a clear difference between running:

```
var blockRecord = db.execute(sql -> sql.select(...).from(...)
            .where(...)
                    .and(...)) // Excess parenthesis here
                    .and(...).fetchOne().value1();
```

And

```
var record = db.execute(sql -> sql.fetch(query));
```

Notice that the second call runs the entire jOOQ logic inside the lambda, whereas the first call seems to not execute any query inside the lambda, but return it unexecuted, and continue building the query outside, and then fetch stuff on what is probably an already closed connection.

Comment: The other guy got to it first in the comments above but I'll up-vote your answer!

Comment: @TheMuscleCode: Yeah, I've noticed just after answering - the comment wasn't displayed to me when I opened the question. It was a close call. Hi there, Knut! :)